# java how to import JAK API/library with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jaxb, jak

this is the API i want to use: https://labs.micromata.de/projects/jak/quickstart.html

i tried to download and unzip the files (including JAXB) but i have no idea what to do with them. how do i add it to my project?
 i searched for how to add API/library but all results told me to import the jar file. did not find any jar file. the unzip folder just looks like a regular project folder. i also tried to export that folder into a jar file, it did not solve the problem, tried to copy and paste the folder into my project, also did not help.

in the doc it says:

> Download the Java API for KML JAR at GitHub and add the JAR to your 
>   classpath.
>    If there are any dependencies, resolve them and add JAXB to
>   your  classpath, too. Version 2.1.xx should be fine.

to add what JAR? i'm really confused

Comment: Download jar from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.micromata.jak/JavaAPIforKml/2.2.0

Comment: thanks, fixed it, why did they link to git hub instead to the file itself?

Comment: I don't know why it says you have to download and put JAXB JARs on the classpath - that is not necessary, because JAXB is part of Java's standard library, it's already included with Java itself.